# Test Network Genesis Block

Tags: network, testnet, bitcoinj, java

I am using BitcoinJ for my java application which fetches the test network's genesis block. I referred to the basics mentioned at JavaWorld and BitcoinJ's Google Code wiki.

I am able to get it running but there seems to be an error while waiting for the node.

I receive the following output :

```
[main] INFO com.google.bitcoin.core.BlockChain - chain head is at height 0:
v1 block: 
   previous block: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   merkle root: 4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b
   time: [1296688602] Thu Feb 03 04:46:42 IST 2011
   difficulty target (nBits): 487063544
   nonce: 384568319

[New I/O boss #9] INFO com.google.bitcoin.core.Peer - com.google.bitcoin.core.Peer$PeerHandler@fe64b9 - Connection refused: no further information
```

Note: I am working from a NAT network, can this be a point of connection failure?

Comment: I think it can't connect to any peers - what does does watching the connection in Wireshark show?

Comment: @NickODell I checked with my network admin, they were blockling port 8333. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: @NickODell Though I still have a query, how long does it take to actually reach till the genesis block? I wrote the code to fetch the genesis block, it kep fetching blocks for 15-20mins and was still fetching them.

Comment: The genesis block ought to be hardcoded. By the way, it shouldn't matter if they're blocking 8333, because testnet runs on 18333

Answer (score 1):

According to OP's comments

> I checked with my network admin, they were blockling port 8333.

probably meaning port 18333